# predicting multivariate time series with little data

Tags: r, time-series

I have 1 week of data formatted in the following way in R.

$$
\begin{array}{c}
\text{Category1} & \text{Category2} & \text{Category3} & \text{Date} & \text{Metric1} & \text{Metric2} & \text{...} & \text{Metric7} \\
\hline
X & a & 1 & 7/1/17 \\
X & a & 2 & 7/2/17 \\
X & b & 1 & 7/3/17
\end{array}
$$

My goal is to predict Metric1 on a future date, ex. 7/15/17.

1st question - can you roughly describe how you might approach this? I have little time-series experience. I'm reading some materials but advice is welcome.

2nd question - broadly speaking, is this even worthwhile when I have only 1 week of data? Am I stuck until I collect more?

related: [Least stupid way to forecast a short multivariate time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24659/least-stupid-way-to-forecast-a-short-multivariate-time-series?rq=1)

Hoping for a bit more explanation or detail, as a time-series beginner. Also that thread doesn't seem to have an accepted answer.